# What is the meaning of setting cpu affinity (e.g. SCHED_SETAFFINITY) on a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu

There are ways to set affinities on processes / threads.
For example, tell the OS to run on specific core only.
Or tell a thread to run on specific core.

What all that mean on a virtual machine, where the cpu is actually virtual (and mapped somehow to the physical cpu) ?

Comment: Virtual machine is Exactly like a regular one you could either share or reserve cpu for this machine. Your vm could do multiple task and you need some to have affinity. I dont understand how or why this question.

Answer (score 1):

It would just set the affinity within the VM and within the virtual CPUs. That might not have a static relationship with the actual host CPUs, but 
assuming the VM host tries to keep virtual CPUs on separate physical CPUs (which it probably should), setting the affinity on the guest might still help in keeping the process on a single CPU, depending on the types of load on the host and on the guest.

If you have as many physical CPUs on the host as virtual ones on the guests, the VM host shouldn't need to move the virtual CPUs around. But since you probably have more virtuals, they'll need to be moved, and there's not much you can do about that in the guest. You'd need to set the affinity on the host level too, if you need it.

That is, assuming there's no special driver to reveal the host system CPUs to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a case where a VM can benefit from [`SCHED_SETAFFINITY(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html). Lets take a "special" VM with 2 "virtual sockets"(mapped and pinned to 2 different physical CPUs on the same host) and 2 "virtual cores" each. You could wanna make sure the proccess you want to set affinity inside the guest to have less performance costs like the one described at the manpages:

> Restricting a thread to run on a single CPU also avoids the
>        performance cost caused by the cache invalidation that occurs when a
>        thread ceases to execute on one CPU and then recommences execution on
>        a different CPU.

Why would you do this kind of setup? I dont know :), but by having 2 virtual sockets you will still have the cache invalidation.

[There is also some benchmarking using 24 cores](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/10/does-corespersocket-affect-performance.html) with multiple dispositions on vmware(1 socket, 24 core - 24 socket, 1 core - 2 socket, 12 core). In the past, this affinity set could be used to software that required a "CPU socket licensing"(cof, cof, Oracle...) once you could proof that the process was bound to a socket, but as for today lots of these solutions are getting clearer on virtual environments licensing, requiring that the whole physical CPUs where the VM runs to be licensed. And as you can see vmware solution creates distincts vNUMAS based on how many vSockets you have.

Other than that, setting affinity inside guests can increase the complexity of something that could be done by setting the affinity at the hypervisor when moving the VM arround.